# connect to a server web service from the global network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, fqdn

here is the situation:

we have a server "srv" that runs tomcat web service.

this web service required that all connection will be using fqdn so that when we connect from our local network to  srv.mydomain:8080/service the service produce a login page that we can connect.

if we`r using only srv.mydomain:8080/service from our local network  we got the login page but when we try to connect there is an error (the service error) that tells that this is not the fqdn.

so far we used this service from our local network, but now we need to connect to the service from any network.

we added a sub domain called service.mydomain.com also did a port forwarding from 8080 to our srv, when we try to access service.mydomain.com:8080/service we get the error that this is not the fqdn.

i must admit we are not familiar with all this IT/Network setups (simple programmers...)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions:

1. Configure tomcat to accept the other domain. Use something like:  `<Host name="srv.mydomain" ......><Alias>service.mydomain.com</Alias> </Host>` See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases
2. Use a *load balancer* or a *reverse proxy*.